# get information of public media using API graph instagram

Tags: facebook-graph-api, instagram-api, instagram-graph-api

The response of API to get media with tag of user does not return any informations about  the user who has posted the media.
Is there a way to get information of those media'user. My app has already the feature instagram public contents

THanks a lot for your replies

Answer (score 0):

You can no longer get user info got hashtag feed using Instagram graph API. You can only get likes count, comments count and caption, no user info.